# Why queryForObject Kotlin extension func returns nullable T? if it actually will throw EmptyResultDataAccessException?

Tags: kotlin, spring-jdbc, spring-kotlin

Using Kotlin and Spring 5 for some simple project.
I would like to get single record from database by id using `queryForObject`. 
My query is a 'simple select by id':

```
jdbc.queryForObject("select id, name from example where id = ?", id)
{ rs: ResultSet, _: Int -> NamedEnt(rs.getLong("id"), rs.getString("name") }
```

In `JdbcOperationsExtensions.kt` it is declared to return nullable type `T?`:

```
fun <T : Any> JdbcOperations.queryForObject(sql: String, vararg args: Any, function: (ResultSet, Int) -> T): T? =
    queryForObject(sql, RowMapper { resultSet, i -> function(resultSet, i) }, *args)
```

In practice when I pass not existing identifier, I face with:

> org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0

Then I do not understand what is the point of returning nullable type? You either receive a single record or exception. Or I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JdbcOperationsExtensions.kt` adds some extension functions to the `org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations` interface (written in Java). If you look at the JavaDocs for `queryForObject` in that, it says:

```
@return the single mapped object (may be {@code null} if the given
{@link RowMapper} returned {@code} null)
```

See [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcOperations.java) for full source code of the `JdbcOperations` Java class.

So the Kotlin-written extension functions need to adhere to this and allow nulls to be returned, hence the nullable type.

Except... as pointed out by @AlexeyRomanov, this particular overload of `queryForObject` takes in a lambda which returns `T`, so can't ever return null, so arguably this overload could return `T`, not `T?`. Maybe it's a bit inconsistent that this lambda in Kotlin can't return null, but the JavaDocs on the very similar overload in the Java class explicitly state that it (`RowMapper`) should be allowed to return null.

Regardless of that point, some other overloads of `queryForObject` simply call to down to the Java-written overload, and because it's written in Java, it's possible that it could return a null. So for them it does seem to make sense for it to be a nullable return value. In which case arguably it's a nice bit of consistency that all the overloads do in fact return the nullable `T`.

Comment: "So the Kotlin-written extension functions need to adhere to this and allow nulls to be returned" Except they don't: `function: (ResultSet, Int) -> T` can't return `null`, so the `RowMapper` using it can't return `null`.

Comment: Ha! Well spotted @AlexeyRomanov: I missed that. I wonder if this is a small bug in that extension method then: maybe the lambda passed into `queryForObject` should be declared as having a return type of `T?`. Because the JavaDocs seem to suggest that the `RowMapper` should be allowed to return null.

Comment: Agreed.  Issue logged [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22682).

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Could you elaborate on why these extensions should be `inline`? Performance?

Comment: Yes. The win is not that large, especially when comparing to database access, but in my opinion you need a reason _not_ to declare such methods inline (e.g. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#public-inline-restrictions). Maybe there is such a reason for this case, I just don't see it.

Comment: If we do that I guess that should apply to any Kotlin extension that invoke it's java counterpart, could you please create an issue for that on https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues ?